# Color coding in Spring framework using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a database that keeps updating often. I want to color code each row according to how old they are showing priority. Something like having a red dot (oldest, 3+ days old) yellow dot (middle, 1-3 days old) or green dot (newest, same day) in the beginning of each row. How do I do this in Spring framework using Thymeleaf? Any suggestions!

Comment: Well the question would be: what did you try? And do you also have timestamps in your database?

Comment: Well, I am very new to Spring and Thymeleaf and not sure where to start. I do have a time stamp on the database.